# I need to find the value in a dynamic h1 element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using python 2.7, Firefox and selenium 3.11

I have the following line with a dynamic number as id:

```
<div class="class1" dojoattachpoint="titleText" dojoattachevent="onmouseover:_mouseOverTitle,onmouseout:_mouseOutTitle,onmousedown:_mouseDownTitle">
<h1 id="_N90399546_title">‪textToFind</h1>
```

I want to locate textToFind.

I have tried the following:

1. `x= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@id='dynamicNumber']")` -> which I was trying when the dynamic number was the same, to see if it worked, but didn't...

   Result: textToFind not found
2. `x= driver.find_element_by_link_text('textToFind')` -> didn't work in a dynamic search

   Result: textToFind not found
3. `x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='class1'][contains(text(),'textToFind')]")`

   Result: textToFind not found
4. `x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='class1'][contains(text(),'textToFind')]").getAttribute("innerHTML")`

   Result: textToFind not found
5. `x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='class1']")`

   Result: textToFind not found

I don't need to extract the text, get attributes, or anything, I just need to find the "textToFind" string. I really appreciate the help.

I have had search several selenium dynamic tutorials, look dozens of websites, search several similar posts in stackoverflow and I can't get to find the text I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Following css selector.

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.class1>h1").text)
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I map the textToFind doing it by css selector?I need to find it by the text...

Comment: @Gusbok : Then try below `xpath`  which is `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(.,'textToFind')]").text)` you might need some waits before elements.

Comment: thank you, I am running the first suggestion, if it doesn't work I will try this one!

Comment: I also tried: x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[contains(.,'textToFind')]").text()

Comment: @Gusbok : What error are you getting? Please check if there any `iframe` present in DOM tree?

Comment: I am getting textToFind not found...same error I got with all my several ways of trying.... let me check the iframe

Comment: I looked for it, but I don't see any iframe

Comment: It is possible to share your url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213349/discussion-between-gusbok-and-kunduk).

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have the fix text string ( **textToFind** in your case ). Then go ahead with following xpath:

   ```
   x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1']/h1[contains(text(),'textToFind')]")
   ```
2. If id is not completely dynamic. Means, if it appends some dynamic number or alphabets either start, end or middle. for example `<h1 id="some-prefix-132dsad233">` then you use following partial match using CSS selector:

   - if fix prefix string e.g. `id="some-prefix-132dsad233"` then `x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1[id^='some-prefix']")`
   - if fix postfix string e.g. `id="132dsad233some-postfix"` then `x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1[id$='some-postfix']")`
   - match some fix text in id e.g. `id="132dsad233some-postfix"` then `x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1[id*='some']")`

You can also use combination of both e.g. `id="hello132dsad233some-postfix"` then `x = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h1[id^='hello'][id$='postfix']")`

Please use other surround element combination to make your locator unique and robust

Comment: Thank you, let me try your suggestions. The ID is 100% dynamic...

Comment: The answer 1 failed, I can't locate the text I am looking,  and the 2 doesn't apply to my case... thank you anyway

Comment: I also tried: X = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='class1' and contains(text(), 'textToFind')]")

Comment: Please update question with actual html snippet of your website

Comment: It's giant, let me try to get the part above of where I am working